# Selecting items in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following dictionary

`d= {"Month":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"Rain":[30,40,50,20,30,70]}`

I want to select certain Rain by ordered by Month, so I get

For example

`new_d= {"Month":[2,4,6],"Rain":[40,20,70]}`

I'm thinking along this side of a code, I'm still new to coding please help how can I do it without dictionary comprehensions?

```
for key in d:
    if filter_string in key:
        # do something
    else:
        # do nothing, continue
```

Answer (score 0):

see below

```
d = {"Month": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]}
interesting_month = [2, 4, 6]
d1 = {'Month': [m for m in interesting_month], 'Rain': [d["Rain"][d['Month'].index(m)] for m in interesting_month]}
print(d1)
```

output

```
{'Month': [2, 4, 6], 'Rain': [40, 20, 70]}
```

Comment: Arlight thanks and what if my month are like this      d = {"Month": [2013-04-01, 2013-07-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-10-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-04-01], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]}

Comment: @Rich - give it a try and see what happen.

Answer (score 0):

first with the for-loop, then as comprehension - as addition to the previous answer:

```
d = {"Month":[1,2,3,4,5,6],"Rain":[30,40,50,20,30,70]}
#new_d = {"Month":[2,4,6],"Rain":[40,20,70]}
mths_to_choose = [2,4,6]

for keyval in d.items():
    new_d[keyval[0]] = []
    for i in mths_to_choose: # if filter_string in key: # do something
        new_d[keyval[0]].append(keyval[1][i-1])
    # else# do nothing, continue  
print(new_d)

new_d = {ditms[0]: [ditms[1][i-1] for i in mths_to_choose] for ditms in d.items()}
print(new_d)
```

output:

```
{'Month': [2, 4, 6], 'Rain': [40, 20, 70]}
{'Month': [2, 4, 6], 'Rain': [40, 20, 70]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might be helpful

```
d = {"Month": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]}

#Creating a new dictionary
new_d = {}

#First Loop: will get the keys from your original dictionary
for keys in d:

    #new_d[keys] = [] - will create an array value for each key found
    new_d[keys] = []

    #Second Loop: will get the values from the array on each key
    for values in d[keys]:

        #If the position of "values" is odd then is inserted on new_d[keys] with the append() method
        if d[keys].index(values) % 2 != 0:
            new_d[keys].append(values)

#Print the outcome
print(new_d)
```

Comment: What about if I have date.    d = {"date": [2013-04-01, 2013-07-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-10-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-04-01], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]}?

Comment: Just replace d = {"Month": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]} with  d = {"date": [2013-04-01, 2013-07-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-10-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-04-01], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]}

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {"Month":[1,2,3,4,5,6], "Rain":[30,40,50,20,30,70]} 
#Desired Output: {"Month":[2,4,6],"Rain":[40,20,70]}

selected_month = [2,4,6] #list of months

new_d = {} #create a new dictionary to store selected month and rain

for key in d.items(): 
    new_d[key[0]] = [] 
    for i in selected_month: 
        new_d[key[0]].append(key[1][i-1])

print(new_d)
```

Comment: What about if i have a date instead of month  d = {"Month": [2013-04-01, 2013-07-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-10-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-04-01], "Rain": [30, 40, 50, 20, 30, 70]}

Comment: Could you add some explanations to this piece of code ?

Comment: @Rich simply just replace the new value of 'Month' with [2013-04-01, 2013-07-01, 2014-03-01, 2014-10-01, 2014-02-01, 2014-04-01] and adjust the selected_month accordingly.